# Reopen activity directly after finishing a phone call

Tags: android, logging, android-activity, phone-call

After I make a call with phone call intent and finish the call, the phone opens calls log instead of directly reopen the app activity which launches the call intent.

How do I skip going to the call log? After finishing the call I want the phone to come back to my app activity?

Comment: Does `startActivityForResult(yourIntent);` help?

Comment: @keyboardsurfer no it doesn't help. any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

launch/reopen the previous activity and set flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to the intent.
if this flag set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the Broadcast of android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE and for the extra EXTRA_STATE. If it is EXTRA_STATE_IDLE the call is finished and you can implement the logic to reopen your app

Comment: I used PhoneStateListener instead of BroadcastListener
What is the code to reopen the app? Tried this but the app crash

Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.muaz", "HantarSMS") );
i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(i);

Comment: Just try to create an Intent on your MainActivity.class, that should be enough. You don't need that other stuff AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Tried this to reopen app but the app crash

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");    
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.muaz", "HantarSMS") );
i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(i);
```